Unable to locate User Model
It seems my model isn't detected. I'm trying to upload my codeigniter site to the web hosting service but I have a problem in my model, it shows this error:

An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: User_model
Filename:
/home/u661467832/domains/pp-quarry.com/public_html/system/core/Loader.php
Line Number: 350
Backtrace:
File:
/home/u661467832/domains/pp-quarry.com/public_html/application/controllers/Absensi.php
Line: 7 Function: __construct
File: /home/u661467832/domains/pp-quarry.com/public_html/index.php
Line: 315 Function: require_once


how do you call your model from the Absensi.php controller? Did you check all naming conventions? How does line 100 of your index.php look like? It's where it says $system_path = "some_path"

Also check the casing of your User_model.php filename, web hosting usually is case-sensitive while localhost is not, so if your file is named for example user_model.php (small u) it might work locally but not on a webserver.

When deploying a CodeIgniter application to a web hosting service, it's important to correctly configure the file structure to ensure that the application functions properly.
Move index.php to public_html:

Place the index.php file inside the public_html directory. This directory is the entry point for the public-facing part of your application.

Move Other Directories Outside public_html:

Move the application/, system/, and vendor/ (if using Composer) directories outside of public_html. This ensures that sensitive application files are not directly accessible from the web.

Sample structure,
/home/user/
│
├── application/          // Application files (outside public_html)
├── system/               // System files (outside public_html)
├── public_html/          // Publicly accessible directory
│   └── index.php         // Entry point of the application
│   └── assets/           // Static files (CSS, JS, images, etc.)


Try this way and hope this resolves the issue.

it said "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php" when trying to move my application and system dir

This does not answer the question, a CI application should also work correctly if all files and folders are uploaded inside public_html. If you're going to move the application and system directories to outside of public_html, make sure to also update their paths in the index.php file (the $system_path and $application_folder variables).
